# React router createMemoryRouter testing not rendering outlet

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-router, react-router-dom, react-testing-library

So I have this **react v6 router** implementation with nested routes using **createBrowserRouter()**. Everything works as expected. Now I want to write a simple test that is testing if a route is getting rendered correctly. So I follow up: https://reactrouter.com/en/main/routers/create-memory-router#creatememoryrouter. I debug the html output of the test, and I see that **RootLayout** got rendered, but with empty **main** tag ... meaning that the **Outlet** tag it's not rendering anything. I placed console.logs inside the route component that it's matching the specific route ( Home component ) ... and it's not getting there.

Implementation

```
const Home = lazy(() => import('../Home'));

export const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    element: <RootLayout />,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        element: <Home />,
      },
    ],
  },
];

export const router = createBrowserRouter(routes);


export default function RootLayout() {
  return (
    <div className="root-layout">
      <main className="root-layout__main">
        <Suspense>
          <Outlet />
        </Suspense>
      </main>
    </div>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  return <RouterProvider router={router} />;
}

export default function Home() {
   return <div>Home page</div>;
}
```

The test

```
it('should navigate to Home', async () => {
  const router = createMemoryRouter(routes, {
    initialEntries: ['/'],
    initialIndex: 1,
  });

  const { debug } = await render(
    <RouterProvider router={router} />
  );

  debug(undefined, Infinity);
});
```

HTML debug result: empty main tag !!!!

```
<body>
  <div className="root-layout">
    <main class="root-layout__main" />
  </div>
</body>
```

Expected debug result

```
<body>
  <div className="root-layout">
    <main class="root-layout__main">
      <div>Home page</div>
    </main>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I'm curious if the `Suspense` and dynamic import is part of the issue in testing. Could you try a normal import of the `Home` component in `routes` file, and remove the `Suspense` component from `Layout`, and retry the test?

Comment: @DrewReese yes, now I see the logs, good hint, curious what comes next

Comment: I suppose that depends on what *exactly* you are really wanting to test. The existing test is IMO not very useful as it seems to be rather testing the `react-router` router component code than anything you specifically own. Just testing that the `Home` component exists in the DOM?

Comment: I need to use await waitFor() because the loading is lazy, and it's async, now it makes sense

Comment: actually I am testing a route build logic, depending on some logic, I build the routes, and I want to test if that path in the router it's getting me to the right route

Comment: Yup, that makes sense to me. Like I said, it depends on what you are really trying to test. I'm guessing the code in your post is just an over-simplification to reproduce the issue you were seeing. Is that close to accurate?

Comment: yes, it's a over-simplification, so actually there is not problem, just me being noob and not able wait for async operation